# Get first element as index to update the rest of the elements within the list

Tags: python, flash

[This is my web output using flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YcUB.png)

registrant_record = [['1', 'James Dommenick Asaria', 'bluesmooth22@gmail.com', '09057367450', 'reg'], ['2', 'Dominador Sultan', 'princessaming@gmail.com', '09363319670', 'reg']]

I would like to get the first element when clicking update button.

Answer (score 0):

```
    registrant_record = [['1', 'James Dommenick Asaria', 'bluesmooth22@gmail.com', '09057367450', 'reg'], ['2', 'Dominador Sultan', 'princessaming@gmail.com', '09363319670', 'reg']]
    registrant_dict={}
    for i in registrant_record:
        registrant_dict[int(i[0])]=i[1:]


    print(registrant_dict[1])
    output
    ['James Dommenick Asaria', 'bluesmooth22@gmail.com', '09057367450', 'reg']

   ##### if you want just the first name ####
    registrant_record = [['1', 'James Dommenick Asaria', 'bluesmooth22@gmail.com', '09057367450', 'reg'], ['2', 'Dominador Sultan', 'princessaming@gmail.com', '09363319670', 'reg']]
    registrant_dict={}
    for i in registrant_record:
        # you want to get the first change i[1] or second element i[2]
        registrant_dict[int(i[0])]=i[1]
    
    print(registrant_dict[1])
    output
    ['James Dommenick Asaria']
```